# How do I get Skyrim to redownload Dawnguard and the other DLC if I accidentally deleted it from the data files menu?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, steam

I've tried restarting many times and going on "View Downloadable Content" but I don't see an option to tell Skyrim to download it again.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Load Steam
2. From the *Library* section, right-click on the game and select
   *Properties* from the menu.
3. Select the *Local files* tab and click the *Verify integrity of game
   cache*... button.

Steam will verify the game's files - this process may take several minutes.
If steam finds that files are missing from the game's directory, it should automatically begin to re-download them. This method has worked for users who are missing DLC [[source]](http://www.overclock.net/t/1255024/help-with-steam-dlc)

Answer (score 0):

I worked perfectly just have to wait and remember that change the load order, you can use a program like loot

https://loot.github.io/

Answer (score -3):

copy Dawnguard.bsa and Dawnguard.esm, then paste them into Data folder in Skyrim directory

Comment: Where are these files coming from?